# How can I group/override the external services in NewRelic's external services in NewRelic?

Tags: java, newrelic, newrelic-platform

I have a Java application that calls out to various domains. The application is a crawler and so this list of domains spans into the hundreds.

[image]

How can I group the list of domains so they appear as a single transaction? Many have suggested that I use Metric Grouping but I'm unsure how to do this?

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/new-relic-solutions/solve-common-issues/troubleshooting/metric-grouping-issues/

The library I'm using for making the network requests is Async HTTP Client. I can see the code for the automatic instrumentation here:

https://github.com/newrelic/newrelic-java-agent/blob/v7.9.0/instrumentation/async-http-client-2.1.0/src/main/java/org/asynchttpclient/AsyncHandler_Instrumentation.java#L64-L68

It is simple but I'm unsure how to override the `uri` for the external transaction?